# from blog.views import (blog_post_detail_page), SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, url, django-models

`hi I was trying to use run server for my Django app that i have created in my directory  that looks like this`

`I was getting this error during runserver from blog.views import (blog_post_detail_page), SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

`

1-try_django
*src
*blog
*init*.py
admin.py
app.py
models.py
test.py
views.py
*tamplest
about.html
base.html
blog_post_detail.html
home.html
title .txt
*try_django.py
**init**.py
setting.py
urls.py
views.py
wsgi.py
**init**.py`

```
#my views looks like:
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import BlogPost

def blog_post_detail_page(request):
    obj = BlogPost.objects.get(id=1)
    template_name = 'blog_post_detail.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

#blog models:
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

#urls :
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from blog.views import (blog_post_detail_page),
from .views import (
    home_page,about_page,contact_page,example_page)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page),
    path('blog',blog_post_detail_page,name='home'),
    path('page/',about_page),
    path('pages/',about_page),
    re_path(r'^pages?/$',about_page),
    re_path(r'^about/$', about_page),
    path('example/', example_page),
    path('contact/', contact_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Syntax Error usually means that you have a typo. Always firstfully check the line it points to.

```
from blog.views import (blog_post_detail_page),
```

In above line you have comma outside tuple. If this is the only thing you are importing from it, then do simple import:

```
from blog.views import blog_post_detail_page
```